# nesting do until eof in do while loop

Tags: sas

Is it possible to nest a `do until (eof)` in a `do until` or `do while` loop? I have not been able to get it to work.

Data

```
data have;
    do i = 1 to 3;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Example - quits after first `j`

```
data want;
    j = 1;
    do while (j < 4);
        do until (eof);
            set have end=eof;
        end;
        call missing(eof);
        output;
        j + 1;
    end;
run;
```

Let me know if I haven't made my problem clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use any type of DO loop inside any other type.

Your particular program is going to stop the first time it tries to run the SET statement on the second iteration of the outer DO loop since there are no more observations to be read.  Most normal SAS data step stop in the same way when they have exhausted their input stream.

If you really want to re-read the whole dataset then use the `POINT=` option on the SET statement.  Make sure to have a way to stop the step since it will no longer be able to read past the end of the input stream.

```
data want;
  do j=1 to 4;
    do p=1 to nobs;
      set have point=p nobs=nobs ;
      * Do something there ;
    end;
    * Do something else here ;
  end;
  * and maybe something here too ;
  stop;
run;
```